# Efficiently querying transactions by time range with activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Is there a way to make this method more efficient?  I am querying a large number of transactions and it seems inefficient to perform a separate activerecord query for each period.

Should I make a single query for the whole day and sort through the results, grouping them by period?  If so, what's the most efficient way to do this?  Look forward to your thoughts.

```
def self.transactions(period)
  today = Date.today
  time1 = Time.utc(today.year, today.month, today.day, 9, 30, 0)
  time2 = Time.utc(today.year, today.month, today.day, 16, 0, 0)
  transactions_by_period = {}

  while time1 < time2
    transactions = self.where("created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?", time1, time2)
    transactions_by_period[time1] = transactions
    time1 += period
  end

return transactions_by_period
end

#todays_transactions_by_hour = Stock.transactions(1.hour)
```

Comment: I say, do it all in the database: fire one query and get back already grouped data. That's what databases are for, handling data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can use ranges for nicer queries. I'd also rename `time1` and `time2` to `start` and `finish`

```
transactions = self.where(:created_at => start..finish)
```

Then you can reduce this to get them by periods.

```
transactions.reduce(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []) do |periods, transaction|
  # Calculate how many periods have gone by for this transaction
  offset = (transaction.created_at - start).to_i / period
  # Find the actual period
  transaction_period = start + offset * period
  periods[transaction_period] << transaction
  periods
end
```

#### Edit

I haven't tested the code, it is shown more for the logic

Comment: I will have to do some experimenting with reduce to get my head around it.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out and was going to comment here, but wasn't sure how to word it.  Great solution, it cuts the benchmark time significantly for this function, especially when querying short periods.  Thanks again.